# Generator for a cyclotomic subextension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Consider the Galois cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{7})/\mathbb{Q}$.

I've found via Galois theorem the following intermediate field of degree 2 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{7}+\zeta_{7}^{2}+\zeta_{7}^{4}).
\end{equation}

Some people told me that I can find a "nice" generator for this field, like $\sqrt{d}$, for some free-square integer $d$.

How can I do such a thing? Are there any references for this type of thing?

Comment: Letting $\xi=\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4$, have you squared $\xi$?

Comment: Okay, here's what I did: I squared it and figured out that $x^{2}+x+2$ (or -2, i don't have my notebook with me right now) is a irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $\xi$ and so, the roots of this polynomial are in the extension and so is $\sqrt{-7}$. Then it was easy to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\xi)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, perfect! For the cubic subfield, it’s a bit more work, but also interesting.

Comment: I found the irreducible polynomial $x^{3}+x^{2}-2x-1$ for the cubic, but couldn't figure out its roots. I read some other topic talking about this and someone said that it isn't possible to express the roots in terms of radicals. Any tips?

Comment: Nah don't tell me, I'll try to figure it out myself. Thanks

Comment: No, no roots, unless you add the cube roots of unity, which is no fun. But if you substitute $x+2$ for $x$ (I forget — maybe $x-2$?) you get a pleasing Eisenstein polynomial.